# Suppose $V=V_1\oplus ...\oplus V_n $. Let $T\in$ Hom$(V,V)$ such that $T(V_i)\subseteq V_i$ for all $i=1,...,n$. Find a basis $\alpha$ of $V$...

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, direct-sum

[image]

I know that a basis for $V$ is of the form $B=B_1\oplus... \oplus   B_n$ where every $B_i$ is base for $V_i$. By hypothesis, I have to $M_i(V_i)\subseteq V_i$ for every $i=1,...,n$. But I could not conclude from this that $B_i=M_i$? 
what you think?

Comment: Why should you need to conclude that $B_i=M_i$? $B_i$ is a set of basis elements and $M_i$ is a matrix.

Comment: @Couchy311 
Yes, you're right, that's not right, so what would be the basis?

Comment: $B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n$ for each $B_i$ a basis for $V_i$ is precisely the basis, so just write out the matrix for $T$ and you'll see that it will exactly take this form.